# How to initiate GSSAPI in potgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I installed postgres in REDHAT 7. Then i installed python 3.6. I had created virtual environment. Also i created a table in postgres. Then i executed this python script and i got some error.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres host=localhost password=postgres")
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/scripts/san-automation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Server not found in Kerberos database
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

cat /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Comment: Are you sure the pg_hba you show is the one actively in use?  It isn't even trying to use GSS, so it is baffling to me why you would get such an error.

Comment: Yes. I did like this, => su postgres =>
bash-4.2$ vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf =>
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it is the one in use.  Can you connect at all, with some other tool?  If so, try `select * from pg_hba_file_rules`, or `show hba_file`

Comment: i didn't connect with any other tools. I just installed and then i changed the hba file. Then i tried to connect with python script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is preemptively loading your gss/kerberos config files (even though it is not going to use them), and finds something it doesn't like in them.  But that appears to be just a warning.  The real error is the last line:

> FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

and I don't think that has anything to do with GSS.  Look in the server's log file to see why ident failed.

If the pg_hba.conf you show is the one in effect, then on your system localhost must be resolving to ::1, not to 127.0.0.1.  That is, it is using ipv6 rather than ipv4.

Comment: now i changed all the 4 connection to trust. but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Did you "reload" or "restart" the server, so that the changes took effect?

Comment: Yes. Now it is working.. systemctl restart postgresql-12.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Now i changed all the connections to trust. Is that ok? or i need to change back to ident

Comment: Since your only entries are for localhost, it is OK if you are the only one using that computer, or you absolutely trust every other user of it.  Changing back to ident would be a good idea, but first you would have to solve the problem of why ident was failing.  You might need to set up a mapping in pg_ident.conf and use that

Comment: If you are on a mac run `pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 restart`

Answer (score 0):

FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

I think the reason for the above error is that the username field in pgAdmin4 is conflicting with the default database username.

check for your default username by typing 'psql --help' in your terminal. resolving the username error fixed my problem